# Binding Input-Property to getter

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

I have created a component article-search with a Input-property like

```
@Input()
public set currentArticle(value : ArticleDto) {
   // ... implementation
}
```

Now, I try to bind it

```
<article-search [currentArticle]="item.article">
</article-search>
```

When I run this, I get the error

> Can't bind to 'currentArticle' since it isn't a known property of
> 'article-search'.

Why is this binding not working?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you missed to add currentArticle to your component tag.like this     <article-search (articleSelected)="setSelectedArticle(item, $event)" [currentArticle]="selectedArticle">
</article-search>

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted the wrong part when I wrote the question. Now I have edited it.

Comment: did you add CommonModule to your Module in import section?